# Transactional Table Performance impact of Materialized View Log

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, materialized-views

I have a table say AccountDetails, where we have customerId, BankAccountId(PK) and balance as columns.
I want to track changes occuring in this table and say for some reason choosing materialized view Log(MVIEW_LOG) on this table to capture changes occuring, Will the performance of update on main table(AccountDetails) will be downgraded as new records created/committed on MVIEW_LOG.
If there are 250+ columns in table will it then cause any impact.

Not concerned about MVIew only MViewLog.

Created MView Log

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON AccountDetails
WITH SEQUENCE(customerId,balance), PRIMARY KEY INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

MView Log created but not sure of performance impact where I have more than 1,000,000 records.